# C#, Use Databinding to fill DatagridView and Filter Rows

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am new to winForm and I am trying to use a DatagridView to display some information from my class.
I use the following code to display my information:

```
        public class Dataclass
        {
           public string FileName {get; set} 
           public string FieldsTotal {get; set} 
           public string Quantity{get; set} 
           public string SelectionColumnTexte {get; set}

           public Dataclass(string fileName, string fieldsTotal, string quantity, string selectionColumnTexte)
           {
               FileName = fileName;
               FieldsTotal = fieldsTotal;
               Quantity= quantity;
               SelectionColumnTexte = selectionColumnTexte;
           }
        }

        public static DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        public static DatagridView dgv = this.Mydatagridview;
        public static BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        public static List<Dataclass> MyDataclass = new List<Dataclass>();
        MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name1","10","10","Select")); 
        MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name2","20","20","Select")); 
        MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name3","30","30","Select")); 
        public static void InitializeDataGridView()
        {
            FillBindingSourceWithClass();
            ModifyDatagridViewParameters();
            CreateDifferentColumnAndFillItWithData();
        }

        public static void FillBindingSourceWithClass()
        {
           foreach (Dataclass Myclass in MyDataclass)
            {
                bindingSource.Add(Myclass);
            }
        }
        public static void ModifyDatagridViewParameters()
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.AutoSize = true;
            dgv.DataSource = bindingSource;
        }
        public static void CreateDifferentColumnAndFillItWithData()
        {
            DataGridViewColumn FileNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            FileNameColumn.Name = "File Name";
            FileNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "FileName";
            dgv.Columns.Add(FileNameColumn);
            DataGridViewColumn FieldsTotalColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            FieldsTotalColumn.Name = "FieldsTotal";
            FieldsTotalColumn.DataPropertyName = "FieldsTotalInFile";
            dgv.Columns.Add(FieldsTotalColumn);
            DataGridViewColumn QuantityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            QuantityColumn.Name = "Quantity";
            QuantityColumn.DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
            dgv.Columns.Add(QuantityColumn);
            DataGridViewColumn SelectionColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            SelectionColumn.Name = "File Selection (Click to multiselect)";
            SelectionColumn.DataPropertyName = "SelectionColumnTexte";
            dgv.Columns.Add(SelectionColumn );
         }
```

At this point my datagridview generate correctly and all my data is visible.
Now I want to filter lines by the File Name Columns and I don't know how I can do that. I have another variable (containing a combobox) to select the file name I want to filter by.
I try to use the BindingSource.Filter but with no success.
Can someone help me with that or explain to me if datagridview structure is too bad? I haven't DataTable (I did not understand its usefulness of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well… the main problem you will have with using a `List<myClass>` with a `BindingSource` is that `List<>` does not implement the `IBindingListView` interface. A `DataTable` does implement this interface and in most examples, you will see a `DataTable` used and not a `List<>`.

Unless you specifically need to use the `BindingSource` it may be easier to simply use LINQ to filter the `List<myClass>` and use it as a data source to the grid. NOTE: there are many advantages to using a `BindingSource` and depending on your needs, you may want to change from a `List<myClass>` to a `DataTable`.

I will assume for this simple example that you want to use a `List<Dataclass>` and below is an example of how you can filter it. Your current code has many typos and it is curious why you did not copy/paste the original code as opposed to re-typing it as it appears you have done.

To start, it appears the code is unnecessarily adding the “Button” text to the data source…? … The “Select” text is added to the DATA SOURCE like…

```
MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name1","10","10","Select"));
```

? … This is very odd and there appears to be no reason to have the string “Select” INSIDE the data source for each `Dataclass` object. So, I have removed that field from the `Dataclass` Class.

Instead, you can add the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` with the “Select” text displayed in all the buttons. The problem with the current code is the line of code…

```
DataGridViewColumn SelectionColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
```

The grids button column has two (2) properties we need to set to set up the “Select” text as we want… however the code above is setting `SelectionColumn` to a generic `DataGridViewColumn` on the left side… so, the properties we need will not available. Therefore, we need to change it to a `DataGridViewBUTTONCOLUMN` to get the properties we need. Something like below should work…

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn SelectionColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
SelectionColumn.Name = "Select"; 
SelectionColumn.Text = "Select";
SelectionColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
SelectionColumn.HeaderText = "File Selection (Click to multiselect)";
```

This should eliminate the need to add the “Select” text to the data source.

The code below drops the `BindingSource` and uses the `List<Dataclass>` as a `DataSource` to the grid. I simplified the code to just two methods and most of the work is done in the forms load event.

We will first set the `List<Dataclass>` as a global variable, however you could avoid this if needed. Also, the line of code below is odd and it is unclear where it is called, however you will have a problem with the line of code…

```
public static DatagridView dgv = this.Mydatagridview;
```

There is really NO need for this… `Mydatagridview` is ALREADY exposed to the code and there is not need to “create” a new variable for it. Therefore, is what I did is simply renamed the grid on the form to `dgv`. This eliminated my need to change all the `dgv` references in the current code.

Try the code below and it should produce the same results in a simpler fashion…

First the altered `Dataclass`…. With the removed `SelectionColumnTexte` property.

```
public class Dataclass {
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public string FieldsTotal { get; set; }
  public string Quantity { get; set; }

  public Dataclass(string fileName, string fieldsTotal, string quantity) {
    FileName = fileName;
    FieldsTotal = fieldsTotal;
    Quantity = quantity;
  }
}
```

Then the code to fill the grid with data…

```
public List<Dataclass> MyDataclass = new List<Dataclass>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name1", "10", "10"));
  MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name2", "20", "20"));
  MyDataclass.Add(new Dataclass("Name3", "30", "30"));
  dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  dgv.AutoSize = true;
  dgv.DataSource = MyDataclass;
  CreateDifferentColumnAndFillItWithData();
}


public void CreateDifferentColumnAndFillItWithData() {
  DataGridViewColumn FileNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  FileNameColumn.Name = "File Name";
  FileNameColumn.DataPropertyName = "FileName";
  dgv.Columns.Add(FileNameColumn);
  DataGridViewColumn FieldsTotalColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  FieldsTotalColumn.Name = "FieldsTotal";
  //FieldsTotalColumn.DataPropertyName = "FieldsTotalInFile";
  FieldsTotalColumn.DataPropertyName = "FieldsTotal";
  dgv.Columns.Add(FieldsTotalColumn);
  DataGridViewColumn QuantityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  QuantityColumn.Name = "Quantity";
  QuantityColumn.DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
  dgv.Columns.Add(QuantityColumn);
  DataGridViewButtonColumn SelectionColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
  SelectionColumn.Name = "Select"; 
  SelectionColumn.Text = "Select";
  SelectionColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
  SelectionColumn.HeaderText = "File Selection (Click to multiselect)";
  dgv.Columns.Add(SelectionColumn);
}
```

And finally, I added a `Button` to the form to demonstrate how you could filter the data in the grid….

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var filter = MyDataclass.Where(x => x.FileName == "Name2").ToList();
  dgv.DataSource = filter;
}
```

Then another `Button` to UN-filter the grid.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dgv.DataSource = MyDataclass;
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Thank you th'at's very usefull and help me to understand. 
I modify my code to post because in the original code there was many references and it could be a little uncomprehensive.
If il use a List<> this is because i get all my information from Files i found on machines and i have many treatement in other methodes. This code is just a little part to display some informations